# Troubleshooting Fedora 24 installation that only works in virtual machine

Tags: fedora, system-installation, virtual-machine, iso

## Error

I get an error error when trying to install Fedora 24 on a new computer I had just built. I choose `Test this media & install Fedora 24` from the boot screen and then get the following error:

```
...
Fragment count: 20
Supported ISO: no
Press [Esc] to abort check.
Checking: 004.8%

The media check is complete, the result is: FAIL

It is not recommended to use this media.
[FAILED] Failed to start Media check on /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-WS-Live-24-1-2.
See 'systemct1 status "checkisomd5@dev-diz-by\\x2dlabel-Fedora\\..."
[   11.192632] dracut-initquene[563]: Job for "checkisomd5@dev-diz-by\\x2dlabel-Fedora\\..." faled because the control process exited with error code. See "checkisomd5@dev-diz-by\\x2dlabel-Fedora\\..." and "journalct1 -xe" for details.[   11.224155] dracut: FATAL: CD check failed!!
[   11.224174] dracut: Refusing to continue

[   11.915103] reboot: System halted
_
```

## Testing

I tested the following to try and find the problem.

- the method I used to write the iso image to the flash drive
- the flash drive
- the computer I was installing on

However, I did some tests and found that none of those three things were the issue. Here's what I did to find that out:

I downloaded an iso image of Fedora 24 and tested it in a virtual machine, where it worked perfectly. Using a MacBook, I followed the instructions on the [Fedora Project Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB) to write the iso file to a flash drive by using `diskutil`. Using my Windows 7 partition of the MacBook, I wrote the iso image to a second flash drive using SUSE Studio ImageWriter and those same instructions. I then tried both flash drives on my newly built computer and the MacBook; all got the same error listed above.

Choosing `Install Fedora 24` at the boot screen instead of `Test this media & install Fedora 24` causes the installation to freeze at some fingerprint authentication daemon.

## Question

Why would it work in a virtual machine but not on a real computer, assuming iso write method, flash drive, or computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded by using a different computer to write the iso image to the flash drive. Apparently, switching partitions on the same computer is not the same as using a different computer altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the media check always fails at 4.8% exactly is that , when you insert a USB into a windows machine, it adds a file to that USB to help with searching and indexing external drives (a practice I disagree with; reading an external drive shouldn't modify it unless explicitly permitted to do so).

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1282244

https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/2246

Anyway, look into"WPSettings.dat" and "System Volume Information" folder. You can disable it, but it may be technical. Solutions can be found online.

Comment: i have this problem after writing fedora 37 iso from xubuntu (older, like 20..) live usb using dd. i have not booted in windows.

Comment: and i tried to run dd from ctrl+alt+fx, after stopping lightdm. and today i tried   linux mint xfce, which was installed 1-2 years ago and updated. the problem is still the same.

Comment: i compared usb with iso, both mounted, with diff - r, and it showed nothing, means no diff.

Comment: i tried dvd-rw and it is ok